# How to check string language in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, text, lang

I have a some text in a list. That text is written in some languages like 'hindi' and 'English.' How can I detect the language of text? The text has no meaning. So how can I detect that `textblob` and `langdetect` library are not working for me because text have no meaning.

Comment: If the text has no meaning, can we really say that it is written in any language?

Comment: We can't say because the meanings are special words. I am asking that how to detect language throw the alphabets of the string. Means that if string have Hindi (devnagri) alphabets. So the language is Hindi. If string have English alphabets (a,b,c...) The language is English.. How to Detect language like this... Help Please...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to know whether a string contains any devnagri/hindi text. This should help:

```
import codecs,string
def is_hindi(character):
    maxchar = max(character)
    if u'\u0900' <= maxchar <= u'\u097f':
        return True
    else:
      return False
```